# How to select a smartphone IR camera for VOC monitoring

Tags: fluid-mechanics, heat-transfer, environmental-engineering, air-quality

I am currently working on a problem involving volatile organic compounds (VOC) source monitoring on some oil and gas transportation environment. I think using infrared (IR) cameras could be a straightforward approach. The core idea is that temperature gradients will indicate the points where there are emission sources.

I am currently comparing IR camera specifications. Some cameras can be literally portable as a smartphone gadget (e.g. Flir ONE) but I'm quite lost on which properties I should look for (gases' and cameras'), in order to find the most practical and cost effective solution. I've thought to start by finding out:

1. Which are the most frequently-occurring VOC in these environments;
2. What are these compounds' most interesting properties (maybe emissivity, absorptivity, transmittance, reflectivity?) Note: Please correct me if I'm wandering off here, as it's been a while since I read any Heat Transfer literature;
3. And how broad can the cameras be in terms of energy spectrum registering.

I am looking for guidance from anyone with practical experience using this method, especially with a gadget like the Flir ONE, or any method of inexpensive, portable VOC monitoring.

Comment: Please elaborate on **exactly** what you hope to accomplish and what your constraints are. This sounds more like a VOC detection problem than a VOC monitoring problem, but without more details it's hard to say what you need. IR camera could be reasonable for leak detection, is this a fugitives control problem? Monitoring typically implies a more quantitative measurement, in this context. I am placing the question on hold, pending your clarifying [edit].